# Remove prefix of variable in generating lombok getter/setter

Tags: java, lombok

I have some code like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class CreditContract {

  private Long _id;
  private String _customerId;

}
```

from which Lombok will generate these setter/getter:

```
public void set_id(Long id) {...}
public Long get_id() {...}
```

How can I control that the underscores are removed? Because I need it like that:

```
public void setId(Long id) {...}
public Long getId() {...}
```

I've found that there is one configuration `lombok.accessors.prefix=_` but I want to control this directly in the class, probably direct in the annotation or with an additional annotation. In other words, I don't want to have a `lombok.config` file.

I couldn't find any information at StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution, too, as Andrey pointed out (https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors):

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(prefix = {"_"})
public class CreditContract {
}
```

This will remove the prefix `_` from my variables when they are used in naming the getter/setter. This can be even used for different prefixes:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Accessors(prefix = {"_", "val})
public class CreditContract {
...
private String valTest;
}
```

Will generate

```
public String getTest(){..}
public void setTest(String string){..}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do believe [@Accessors annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/Accessors) will help